# Is there any difference in meaning between the phrase "take someone's word for it" and "take someone at their word"?

Tags: difference, phrases

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning and usage between the phrase *take someone's word for it* and *take someone at their word*? For example:

> Sara told me that she would keep her promise. I had no choice but to **take her word for it**.
>
> Sara told me that she would keep her promise. I had no choice but to **take her at her word**.

Comment: No, I don't think there is any difference.

Comment: In that particular case, there **is** a difference. _Take someone's word for `X`_ means believe `X` because someone has sworn to it. In this case, `X` is _her promise_. In other words, this is a promise about a promise. How trustworthy is that? By the way, the idiom is _have **no** choice but to_. Not _not choice_; negatives are so fussy.

Comment: Sworn? An oath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some dictionaries state that the two expressions have the same meaning, but there are some situations where you would use one but not the other. According to Cambridge Dictionary (and I am aware of this nuance in everyday life) to take someone's word for something means:

> to believe that what someone is saying is true

*When my son said he did not break the neighbour's window, I took his word for it.*

There is often the nuance that someone believed someone else without checking; it does not always imply implicit belief.

[Take someone's word for it](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-someone-s-word-for-it?q=take%20someone%27s%20word%20for%20it)

However to take someone at their word means (my emphasis):

> to believe (someone) without question **and act according to their words**

*When my boss said it was time to change the furniture in the office, I took her at her word and ordered new desks and chairs.*

[Take someone at his word](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-norwegian/take-someone-at-his-her-word)